# need to import info from text file to sql using vba

Tags: sql, vba, file, text, import

This is what my text file looks like - Variables are on the left and data is on the right

```
; ------- Test #01 -------


Method      , Ping
;--- Common properties ---
;DestFolder , Root\Black\
RMAgent     , Black
Title       , Black - Agent not connected
Comment     , Ping mra itself
RelatedURL  , 
NamePattern , %agent% - Agent not connected
CmntPattern , Ping %host%
ScheduleMode, Regular
Schedule    , 
Interval    , 600
Alerts      , Send AM Email
ReverseAlert, No
UnknownIsBad, Yes
WarningIsBad, Yes
UseCommonLog, Yes
PrivLogMode , Default
CommLogMode , Default
```

This is my code so far

```vb
Public Sub Load_Module1(ByVal FileName As String, ByVal LogFile As String)

End Sub

Sub main()

    Dim fs As FileStream
    Dim sw As StreamReader
    Dim strNewFileName As String
    Dim strFileExt As String
    Dim intPos As Integer
    Dim strColumnData As String() = Nothing
    Dim intRow As Integer = 1
    Dim strLine As String
    'Dim strSubString As String

    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Do the Common Table
    '-----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim strDBConnection As String = "Data Source=*******;Initial Catalog=*******;User Id=*******;Password=*******"
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(strDBConnection)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("appsp_host_import", cn)
    Const filename As String = "C:\Temp\HostMonitorTests2015-09-11change.txt.txt"
    Dim dataArray() As String
    Dim filenumber As Integer = FreeFile()
    Dim strmethod As String
    Dim strDestFolder As String
    Dim strRMAgent As String
    Dim strTitle As String
    Dim strComment As String
    Dim strRelatedURL As String
    Dim strNamePattern As String
    Dim strCmntPattern As String
    Dim strScheduleMode As String
    Dim strSchedule As String
    Dim strInterval As Integer
    Dim strAlerts As String
    Dim strReverseAlert As Boolean
    Dim strUnknownIsBad As Boolean
    Dim strWarningIsBad As Boolean
    Dim strUseCommonLog As Boolean
    Dim strPrivLogMode As String
    Dim strCommLogMode As String
    Dim strtype As String
    Dim strImportRow As String
    Dim strLastOrderNum As String = ""
    Dim intImportID As Integer
    Dim intLineNum As Integer
    Dim intQtyOrdered As Integer




    Try
        fs = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        sw = New StreamReader(filename)
    Catch e As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    strLine = sw.ReadLine()
    'Dim TextLine As String
    '' Open file.

    '' Loop until end of file. 
    'Do While Not EOF(1)
    '    ' Read line into variable.
    '    TextLine = LineInput(1)
    '    ' Display result in a message box.
    '    MsgBox("End of file reached at " & TextLine)
    'Loop
    'FileClose(1)
    Dim pos As Integer = InStr("; ------- Test #01 -------")

    While Not sw.EndOfStream
        If filename.Contains("; ------- Test #01 -------") Then
            cn.Open()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DestFolder", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RMAgent", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comment", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@RelatedURL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NamePattern", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CmntPattern", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ScheduleMode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Schedule", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Interval", SqlDbType.Int)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Alerts", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReverseAlert", SqlDbType.Bit)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnknownIsBad", SqlDbType.Bit)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@WarningIsBad", SqlDbType.Bit)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UseCommonLog", SqlDbType.Bit)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrivLogMode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommLogMode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SyncCounters", SqlDbType.Bit)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@SyncAlerts", SqlDbType.Bit)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DependsOn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Testspecific", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
        End If
        strtype = Mid(strLine, 13, 1)
        Select Case strtype
            Case "Method"
                strmethod = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case ";DestFolder"
                strDestFolder = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "RMAgent"
                strRMAgent = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "Title"
                strTitle = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "Comment"
                strComment = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "RelatedURL"
                strRelatedURL = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "NamePattern"
                strNamePattern = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "CmntPattern"
                strCmntPattern = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "ScheduleMode"
                strScheduleMode = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "Schedule"
                strSchedule = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "Interval"
                strInterval = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "Alerts"
                strAlerts = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "ReverseAlert"
                strReverseAlert = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "UnknownIsBad"
                strUnknownIsBad = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "WarningIsBad"
                strWarningIsBad = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "UseCommonLog"
                strUseCommonLog = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "PrivLogMode"
                strPrivLogMode = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
            Case "CommLogMod"
                strCommLogMode = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 99))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters("@Reset").Value = 0
        End Select
        filenumber = 0
        'sw.Close()
        'fs.Close()
        cn.Close()
    End While
    FileClose(1)

    'Try
    '    cn.Open()
    '    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DestFolder", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RMAgent", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comment", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RelatedURL", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@NamePattern", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CmntPattern", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ScheduleMode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Schedule", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Interval", SqlDbType.Int)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Alerts", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReverseAlert", SqlDbType.Bit)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnknownIsBad", SqlDbType.Bit)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WarningIsBad", SqlDbType.Bit)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UseCommonLog", SqlDbType.Bit)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PrivLogMode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CommLogMode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SyncCounters", SqlDbType.Bit)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SyncAlerts", SqlDbType.Bit)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@DependsOn", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Testspecific", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
    '    'cmd.Parameters("@Reset").Value = 1


    'Catch e As Exception
    '    Exit Sub
    'End Try

    If Not sw.EndOfStream Then
        strLine = sw.ReadLine()     'Get the header line
    End If

    While Not sw.EndOfStream
        Try
            strLine = sw.ReadLine()
            intRow = intRow + 1
            If UCase(Mid(strLine, 1, 3)) = "YES" Or UCase(Mid(strLine, 1, 3)) = "NO " Then
                cmd.Parameters("@DestFolder").Value = UCase(Trim(Mid(strLine, 1, 3)))
                cmd.Parameters("@RMAgent").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 7, 6))
                cmd.Parameters("@Title").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 15))
                cmd.Parameters("@Comment").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 14, 15))
                cmd.Parameters("@RelatedURL").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 47, 5))
                cmd.Parameters("@NamePattern").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 52, 5))
                cmd.Parameters("@CmntPattern").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 60, 8))
                cmd.Parameters("@ScheduleMode").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 69, 8))
                cmd.Parameters("@Schedule").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 83, 6))
                cmd.Parameters("@Interval").Value = CInt(Trim(Mid(strLine, 78, 4)))
                cmd.Parameters("@Alerts").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 83, 6))
                cmd.Parameters("@ReverseAlert").Value = 0
                cmd.Parameters("@UnknownIsBad").Value = 0
                cmd.Parameters("@WarningIsBad").Value = 0
                cmd.Parameters("@UseCommonLog").Value = 0
                cmd.Parameters("@PrivLogMode").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 175, 7))
                cmd.Parameters("@CommLogMode").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 175, 7))
                cmd.Parameters("@SyncCounters").Value = 0
                cmd.Parameters("@SyncAlerts").Value = 0
                cmd.Parameters("@DependsOn").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 175, 7))
                cmd.Parameters("@Testspecific").Value = Trim(Mid(strLine, 175, 7))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.Parameters("@Reset").Value = 0
            End If
        Catch e As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try
    End While
    sw.Close()
    fs.Close()
    cn.Close()

    'Move the file
    intPos = filename.Length
    While intPos > 0
        If Mid(filename, intPos, 1) = "  " Then
            Exit While
        End If
        intPos = intPos - 1
    End While
    strNewFileName = Left(filename, intPos)
    strNewFileName = strNewFileName & "Archive\" & Mid(filename, intPos + 1, 999)
    strFileExt = "_" & Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss") & ".txt"
    strNewFileName = strNewFileName.Replace(".txt", strFileExt)
    Try
        System.IO.File.Move(filename, strNewFileName)
    Catch e As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: its not working properly and i cannot figure out how to get the data to differentiate between a variable and data. also i cannot figure out how to get the code to look for where it starts. i used almost all tutorials from this site and many others with no solution.

Comment: Well, I don't know much about VB but it looks to me like a good deal of your logic is commented out. What I suggest you look into is how to 1) read a line of data in from a file and 2) split that line on a delimiter, in this case a comma. That should get you on the right start.

Comment: i understand all that but how would the code know when to start reading the textfile? i commented out code that was not work properly for my project.

Comment: Well, like I said I don't know VB but `Dim pos As Integer = InStr("; ------- Test #01 -------")` and ` If filename.Contains("; ------- Test #01 -------") Then` seem awfully dodgy to me. I suggest you back up and break this into chunks. Right a program that reads and prints a file. Once you get that working, start on parsing the data correctly. As it stands this is far too large of an code dump to be able to get close to figuring our what the problem is.

Comment: btw i have a table and stored procedure setup in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Here is the first problem:

```
strtype = Mid(strLine, 13, 1)
```

It should be

```
strtype = Mid(strLine, 1, 13)
```

or more readable

```
strtype = Left(strLine, 13)
```

---

Since when does VBA have `Try ... Catch`? Does this code compile?

Comment: yes the try and catch work and thanks for pointing that problem out to me. thats one fix ton more to go lol thanks again

Comment: Actually that was a little hint that your tags are wrong :)  `Try ... Catch` is not VBA but VB.Net (I guess that's what you are using?) @ayono

Comment: correct sorry but the tag mess up. more focused on getting this to work. i have put a lot of hours into understanding this

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try
        cn.Open()
        cmd = new SqlCommand(srtQuery, cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Method", SqlDbType.VarChar)

        .
        .
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Testspecific", SqlDbType.VarChar, 512)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

   Catch sqlEx as SqlException
   'Do something about the exception

   Catch ex as Exception
   Throw 'Re-throw any other exception


   Finally
  cn.Close();
   End Try
```